# Using Grammarly in Article writing

Tags: publications, writing, software, tools

I'm sure you have heard about or seen Grammarly app's ads. Do you recommend using it to proof read your articles before sending them for review?

Comment: This sounds like an advertisement for Grammarly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an advertisement for a specific product.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an advertisement to me, unless you think that everyone is going to say Grammarly is good! It sounds like a reasonable question from a person who is unsure of the quality of their written English.

Comment: I don't see any difference between using Grammerly and using a spelling checker.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I don't think our site is large enough for Grammarly to give a damn about us tbh

Comment: VTC as opinion-based. Personally, I have stopped using it for privacy concerns, but having suggestions is actually terrific. Now I am trying to refer to *Elements of Style* every now and then, but it takes lots of time, and my writing is still beyond poor, which is highly regrettable :( Does not help that English writing is so dependent on one's active vocabulary...

Answer (score 1):

My experience of Grammarly is that it provides very good help for native and non-native speakers alike. Moreover, despite fears that it might obliterate one's own *style* and make everyone sound the same, that turns out not to be true. Even after Grammarly has run it's electronic "eye" over my writing, it still sounds like *my* writing as opposed to sounding like that of a co-author who wrote a different section of our joint paper.